# can't call methods from SEAM Component

Tags: methods, components, seam, call, seam2

i have a SEAM 2 application and i have a strange situation. I'm developing with Eclipse Indigo, and i need to create a page with a grid where each row has a button that display a popup window with a list and you can choose one item of the list with a link and the value selected is shown in the row.

So i have this component:

```
@Name("paramContHome")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class ParamContHome extends KubeDAO<ParametroSistema>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @In
    private LoginUser loginUser;

    @In(required=false,create=true)
    private CuentaContHome cuentaContHome;

    public void load(){
        try{
            setInstance(getEntityManager().find(ParametroSistema.class, prctId));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            clearInstance();
            setInstance(new ParametroSistema());
        }
    }

    public void selCuentaParam(ParametroSistema par) {
        setSelParam(par);
        cuentaContHome.getCuentasList();
    }

    public void setCuentaParam(CuentaContable cta) {
        selParam.setValorNum(cta.getId().floatValue());
        selParam.setSelObj(cta);
    }

    ...

    }
```

That contains the methods that i'm trying to call from xhtml page. This is the xhtml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    template="/layout/templateKu.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
        <rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="header">#{app.paramact_head}</f:facet>
            <rich:spacer height="20" />
            <h:form id="formA">
                <p:growl globalOnly="true" sticky="false" life="3000" />
                <p:focus />
                <a:queue name="q1" />

                <rich:dataTable var="res" value="#{paramContHome.resultList}"
                    rendered="#{not empty paramContHome.resultList}" rows="10"
                    align="center" rowClasses="tableInfo1 tableInfo2"
                    headerClass="tablaHeader" footerClass="tableScroll">
                    <f:facet name="header">#{app.paramact_list}</f:facet>

                    <rich:column filterBy="#{res.nombre}" filterEvent="onkeyup">
                        <f:facet name="header">#{app.paramact_nombre}</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{res.nombre}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">#{app.transferencia_valornum}</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{res.selObj.nombre}" size="20" >
                            <a:support event="onblur" ajaxSingle="true" eventsQueue="q1" reRender="_table"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                        <a:commandButton ajaxSingle="true"   
                            action="#{paramContHome.selCuentaParam(res)}" reRender="sCta" 
                            onclick="#{rich:component('selCta')}.show();"
                            styleClass="modifyBtn" value=" " style="width:30px;">
                        </a:commandButton>
                    </rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <rich:datascroller id="ds1" renderIfSinglePage="true" />
                    </f:facet>
                </rich:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </rich:panel>
        <rich:modalPanel id="selCta" width="400" moveable="false" autosized="true" top="50px" 
            onbeforeshow="activeModal.setActiveModalPanel('selCta');">
            <f:facet name="header">#{app.general_lov}</f:facet>
            <f:facet name="controls">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:graphicImage value="/kubeImg/close.png" styleClass="closeBtn" 
                        onclick="#{rich:component('selCta')}.hide();" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <s:div id="sCta"><ui:include  src="selCta.xhtml" /></s:div>
        </rich:modalPanel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This is the button where i wanna call the method selCuentaParam of component paramContHome:

```
<rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">#{app.transferencia_valornum}</f:facet>
    <h:inputText value="#{res.selObj.nombre}" size="20" >
        <a:support event="onblur" ajaxSingle="true" eventsQueue="q1" reRender="_table"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <a:commandButton ajaxSingle="true"   
        action="#{paramContHome.selCuentaParam(res)}" reRender="sCta" 
        onclick="#{rich:component('selCta')}.show();"
        styleClass="modifyBtn" value=" " style="width:30px;">
    </a:commandButton>
</rich:column>
```

Inside this method, i call a method from another component, cuentaContHome:

```
@In(required=false,create=true)
private CuentaContHome cuentaContHome;
...
public void selCuentaParam(ParametroSistema par) {
setSelParam(par);
cuentaContHome.getCuentasList();
}
```

But when i run the application and enter to the page, and i press the button, it doesn't calle the method selCuentaParam. I've checked this because i put breakpoints inside it and put System.out.println and doesn't invoke it. Do you know why this happens, is something related to component initialization?

Regards.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a component initialization problem (otherwise you'd be getting NullPointerExceptions). What happens when you press the button? any error page is displayed, or something in the console?

Comment: No, nothing happens. In the output i get this:

`19:53:39,911 WARN  [Component] Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: entityManager(CONVERSATION)`

But this is normal and i get this in other screens or catalogs of the application and i don't have problem.

Comment: Have you tried enabling Seam's [debug mode](http://community.jboss.org/message/523017)? and how about the application server's logs? It's hard to figure out what's happening without more information. Please post here any further debug info that you can come up with.

Comment: `
05:38:07,386 WARN  [Component] Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: entityManager(CONVERSATION)
05:38:12,150 WARN  [Component] Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: entityManager(CONVERSATION)
05:39:26,245 WARN  [Component] Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: entityManager(CONVERSATION)
05:39:47,306 WARN  [Component] Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: entityManager(CONVERSATION)
05:39:47,421 WARN  [Component] Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: entityManager(CONVERSATION)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found the problem, i think. In my screens i follow a certain pattern: First i have a xhtml where i show a grid of database records with a button to go to a second xhtml wich has a form to create a new record. This button begins a conversation, so in the xhtml that has a form (i call it detail.xhtml) it begins the conversation or joins to existing one. So, i modified the pages.xml of the first xhtml (i call it list.xhtml) in the next way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages-2.2.xsd">
 <action execute="#{paramContHome.getParametrosContables()}" on-postback="false"/>

       <begin-conversation propagation="begin" join="true" />

</page>
```

I used first just `<begin-conversation />` and  but it gives me this exception `begin() called from long-running conversation, try join=true` so i added this to begin-conversation and it works!!